# Sonarqube binaries not found on project with two modules

Tags: java, android, sonarqube

I have an Android project with two modules and I'm try to configure Sonarqube to make it work with the multi module analysis properties. I have three properties files:

Properties file 1, on the root project:

```
sonar.projectKey=MyProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.binaries=**/classes/**
sonar.modules=module1,module2
```

Properties file 1, on the module 1

```
sonar.projectName=myproject/module1
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
```

Properties file 2, on the module 2

```
sonar.projectName=myproject/module2
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
```

Problem is Sonarqube crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching '**/classes/**'
```

What I tried so far was to move the `sonar.java.binaries=**/classes/**` line to each module, but Sonar throws the same exception.
I also try to set the `sonar.java.binaries=/build/intermediates/classes` but it didn't work either.
The most strange thing is, if I create only one properties file in the root project like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=MyProject
sonar.projectName=myproject/module1
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.binaries=**/classes/**
```

It works! Why with modules configuration I have problems with the binaries?

Edit: Sonarqube version is 6.7.6, Sonarjava 5.9.2, Java 1.8

Comment: For my understanding, why not using the Scanner for Gradle? https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html

Comment: Due to our Jenkins configuration

Comment: The behavior may depend on the version of the Java analyzer used, so it would be good to include that in your post, and the version of SonarQube and scanner too. If you can package a minimal reproducer, that would greatly help answering.

Comment: @janos included Sonar and scanner versions.